# Attach Hiddenfield to HTML Markup

Tags: asp.net

I am attaching an object to my aspx page. Since the object's type is determined at runtime, I want to be able to set the value of this object's type parameter to a hiddenfield value which I set when I run my web application.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField1" runat="server" />

<object id="myObject"
        type="hiddenfield1.value???">
</object>
```

As you can see in the code snippet above, I need to set the type to the hiddenfield's value.  How do I go about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but you want to pass the type of an object to the client in a hidden value?

Well I'd do somehting like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="ObjectType" runat="server" value="<%= typeOf(MyObject).toString() %>" />
```

I recently uninstalled visual web developer so I can't really tell you if this works or not, but it should.

If this is not what you intended or if it doesn't work, please drop me a comment.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts for you:

1. Make the Object a server control - runat="server" - then in code-behind set the 'type' Attribute to HiddenField1.Value (i.e. Object1.Attributes["type"] = HiddenField1.Value. I tried this in a quick test but had trouble setting the classid attribute of the object when I set runat="server". Some fiddling may be needed.
2. Generate the HTML Object tag entirely in code-behind in a string variable then inject it into a Literal control. As you're generating the string variable, reference the HiddenField1.Value. (i.e. `string myObject = "<object id="Object1" classid="..." type='" + HiddenField1.Value + "' ></object"`).
3. Use JavaScript (or a JS framework) to set the 's 'type' value to that of the rendered hidden field's value.